# In setContentView(R.layout.activity_second), the activity_second is red

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, layout

This is a new empty activity btw.
The IDE says that there is no activity_second.xml, so I tried to create it but then it says "activity_second.xml already exists".
Then I recreated activity_second.xml but it changed nothing.

I am a beginner pls help me... ty.

Comment: Hi, can you share a screen shot of your project? to try to understand better where could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just restart your android studio and again check! Sometimes it happens with me also.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio can be buggy sometimes. Usually, these issues can be solved by restarting Android Studio. If it still doesn't solve your issue, try invalidating caches.

In your Android Studio, click **File(Menu)->Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: Perhaps you can upvote my answer by clicking upper arrow right there :) Thanks. @Eralf

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below 2 steps to fix this common issue-

**1.)** Try to rebuild your project by **Build > Rebuild** from the menu bar.

If the above solution doesn't solve your problem

**2.)** Try **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...** and open the same project again.